# touchpad raw input

Tags: drivers, touchpad, input-devices

I am researching the extra possibilities for using a laptop touchpad as an input device apart from mouse movement.

How do I hook and listen to raw data coming from touchpad driver?

Answer (score 2):

First, find your system's TouchPad driver, by
    `zgrep -i touchpad /var/log/dmesg*`
On my system (yours may be different) it is
    `input: AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7`
Doing
    `ls -lRA /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7`
(Note the added **/sys**). showed some interesting files, but
    `man -k touchpad`
led me to
    `man synaptics`
which says:
     `synaptics - touchpad input driver

    DESCRIPTION

       synaptics is an Xorg input driver for touchpads.  Even though touchpads can be

       handled by the normal evdev or mouse drivers, this driver allows more advanced

       features of the touchpad to  become  available.`